# Integration practice of $\int \frac{\sqrt{25-y^2}}{y}dy$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I need to solve $\int \frac{\sqrt{25-y^2}}{y}dy$.

I originally thought IBP, but that led to a very large and confusing algebra problem.

Then I started to look at the $\sqrt{25-y^2}$ and started to consider doing a $u$-substituion, and letting $u=\sin\theta$ and $du=\cos\theta d\theta$. Once I started playing a bit, the intuition was lost.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Try $y=5\sin\theta$, this will work.

Answer (score 10):

Trigonometric substitutions are not necessary.  Let $u^2 = 25 - y^2$, so that $2u \, du = -2y \, dy$.  Then $$\begin{align*} \int \frac{\sqrt{25-y^2}}{y} \, dy &= - \int \frac{-y \sqrt{25-y^2}}{y^2} \, dy \\ &= - \int \frac{u \sqrt{u^2}}{25-u^2} \, du \\ &= \int \frac{u^2 - 25 + 25}{u^2 - 25} \, du \\ &= u + 25 \int \frac{du}{u^2 - 25} \\ &= u + \frac{5}{2} \int \left(\frac{1}{u-5} - \frac{1}{u+5} \,\right) du\end{align*}$$ and the rest is obvious.

Comment: Nice! just a point in mathematical writing: As far as I know, the differential operator in ${\rm d}x$, as it is an operator and not a scalar or etc, it is supposed to be written in roman font style.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=5 \sin u$, then you have

\begin{eqnarray}{c}
\int \frac{\sqrt{25-y^2}}{y}{\rm d}y &=&
\int \frac{\sqrt{25-25\sin^2u}}{5\sin u}5\cos u\ {\rm d}{u}
\\& =&
\int \frac{\cos u}{\sin u}5\cos u\ {\rm d}{u} 
\\& =&
5\int \frac{\cos^2 u}{\sin u}\ {\rm d}{u} 
\\& =&
5\int \frac{1-\sin^2 u}{\sin u}\ {\rm d}{u} 
\\& =&
5\int \frac{1}{\sin u}-\sin u\ {\rm d}{u} 
\\& =&
5\int \csc u-\sin u\ {\rm d}{u} 
\\& =&
\ -5\ln \left |\csc u + \cot u\right | - 5\cos u + C.
\end{eqnarray}
Now substitute $u$ with $\arcsin y$.