# What is an easy way to integrate $\int_0^5 \frac{v^3 }{2\sqrt{25-v^2}} dv$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This does not appear to be a difficult integral.

I am wondering if there was an easy way to do it.

Comment: smells like a substitution like $v = 5\sin(t)$ or something similar would do it, where $t$ ranges from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: done that, thanks

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867085/integration-practice-of-int-frac-sqrt25-y2ydy

Answer (score 8):

Setting  $\displaystyle\sqrt{25-v^2}=u\implies 25-v^2=u^2\iff v^2=25-u^2, v\ dv=-u\ du$

$$\int\frac{v^3}{\sqrt{25-v^2}}dv=\int\frac{v(v^2)}{\sqrt{25-v^2}}dv=\int\frac{(25-u^2)}u(-u\ du)=\int(u^2-25)du$$

Observe that this pattern holds true whenever the numerator contains only odd powers of $v$

Comment: And this is why you shouldn't always leap to trig substitution.

Comment: I think one needs a typo fix, the integral is even simpler.

Comment: There is no $u$ at the denominator, is there?

Comment: My computation was almost identical but slightly different:  $$u = (25-v^2)^{1/2}, \quad du = -v(25-v^2)^{-1/2} \, dv, \quad v^2 = 25-u^2$$ immediately gives $$v^3(25-v^2)^{-1/2} \, dv = (u^2 - 25)\, du.$$

Answer (score 4):

Use substitution $25-v^2=x$

$-2vdv=dx$

$ \int_0^5 \dfrac{v^3 }{2\sqrt{25-v^2}} dv=\int_{25}^{0}\frac{-(25-x)dx}{4\sqrt{x}}=\int_{0}^{25}(\frac{25}{4}x^{\frac{-1}{2}}-\frac{1}{4}x^{\frac{1}{2}})dx=\frac{125}{3}$

Comment: @Semiclassical first i write only hint but when i see other people give the answer then i completely solve it

Answer (score 2):

Let $v = 5\sin \theta$. So $dv = 5\cos \theta d\theta$. 
$$
\int \dfrac{v^3dv}{\sqrt{25 - v^2}} = \int \dfrac{5^3\sin^3 \theta \ 5\cos \theta d\theta}{5\cos \theta} = 125\int (1 - \cos^2 \theta)\sin \theta d\theta 
$$
$$
= 125\int (\cos^2\theta - 1)d(\cos \theta) = \dfrac{125\cos^3\theta}{3} - \cos \theta + C
$$

Answer (score 2):

One can use indeed $v = 5 \sin(\phi)$, then

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^5 \frac{v^3}{2\sqrt{25-5v^2}} dv
&=& \frac{125}{2} \int_0^{\pi/2}  \sin(\phi) \Big( 1 - \cos^2(\phi) \Big) d\phi\\
&=& \frac{125}{2} \Big( 2 - \frac{1}{3} \Big)\\
&=& \frac{125}{3}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I'd do is get rid of all the $5$'s, by writing the integral as

$$\int_0^1{(5u)^3\over2\sqrt{25-(5u)^2}}(5du)={125\over2}\int_0^1{u^3\over\sqrt{1-u^2}}du$$

Next, writing $u^3=u-u(1-u^2)$, one gets

$$\int{u^3\over\sqrt{1-u^2}}du=\int{u\over\sqrt{1-u^2}}du-\int u\sqrt{1-u^2}du$$

Each of these can be integrated "by eye," bypassing the need to make an explicit substitution:

$$\int_0^1{u\over\sqrt{1-u^2}}du=\int_0^1 u(1-u^2)^{-1/2}du=-(1-u^2)^{1/2}\Big|_0^1=1$$
and
$$\int_0^1 u\sqrt{1-u^2}du=\int_0^1 u(1-u^2)^{1/2}=-{1\over3}(1-u^2)^{3/2}\Big|_0^1={1\over3}$$

Thus

$$\int_0^1{(5u)^3\over2\sqrt{25-(5u)^2}}(5du)={125\over2}\left(1-{1\over3}\right)={125\over3}$$

as other answers have found.

(One note:  I find I have to be very careful in the "eyeball substition" step to make sure I've got the correct sign and fraction for the antiderivative.  It's easy to make a mistake, so it's sometimes smart to make the substitution explicit.  On the other hand, the more stuff you write down, the more opportunity there is to write down the wrong thing....)

Answer (score 1):

Setting $v = 5\sin(t)$, where $t \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, so that we have the same range for $v$ in $[0,5]$, we get that $\sqrt{25-v^2} = \sqrt{25(1-\sin^2(t))} = 5\cos(t)$, as $\cos(t)$ is positive on the $t$-range. Also, $dv = 5\cos(t)dt$ and $v^3 = 125\sin^3(t)$. Substituting this in the integral we get that it equals $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 125\sin^3(t)dt$, which should be doable.

Comment: It should be $\int_0^{\pi/2} 125 sin^\color{red}{3}(t) dt$...

Comment: Quite right, I'll correct it